# Should all interface and type declarations for a module go inside one file?

Tags: typescript

Currently, I declare my types and interfaces in the same file as the logic. However, I find myself needing to reuse some of the types and interfaces I created in another file often. I end up having types and interfaces in every file and not knowing where to import what.

Is it better to create a single type/interface file for a single feature? For example, all login page types and interfaces are inside `loginTypes.ts`. This way, I always know where to import the types I need.

Answer (score 3):

Generally id suggest declaring interfaces & types context oriented. So that your `login.ts`, containing all the login logic, does also export all related type (e.g. `LoginApiResponse`). If multiple files have a nested concern structre (e.g. `login.ts`, `accessTokenLogin.ts`, `twoFactorAuth`...) where `login.ts` is the brodest member, which brings all the sub functinallity together, id recommend reexporting all in sub modules declared interfaces there as well. So that you would have:

---

`login.ts`

```
export interface GeneralLoginInterface {
  prop: string
}

export { Responce } from "./twoFactorAuth.ts"
```

And import only from `login.ts` (note: this can be extended to actual code (classes functions etc.) as well).

If members of your subclass have confilicting names (when both `twoFactorAuth.ts` and `accessTokenLogin.ts` have a Response type), consider exporting them under different namspaces like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61890299/10226440).

---

Note that this is just an opinion, you can import types all over the place and wont have to worry about circular dependencies, since types get stripped away at runtime anyway.