# How should I export multiple groups of classes/interfaces from a package

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces

I have a typescript package where I have 2 groups of classes/interfaces: writeAPI and readAPI.
Both API's have identically named classes, for example there is a writable 'Node' and a readable 'Node'.

I would like to prevent to add the group in the name of the class, like so: 'WritableNode', 'ReadableNode'.

Is it possible to create a package that can be consumed by another package as follows:
1)

```
import * as myAPIs from "myAPIs"

const readableNode = new myAPIs.readable.Node()
const writableNode = new myAPIs.writable.Node()
```

or alternatively (less preferred):
2)

```
import * as myReadableAPI from "myAPIs/readable"
import * as myWritableAPI from "myAPIs/writable"

const readableNode = new myReadableAPIs.Node()
const writableNode = new myWritableAPIs.Node()
```

edit:

this seems to work (for my package specifically):

```
import * as myReadableAPI from "myAPIs/dist/src/readable
```

I find it ugly and long, I would like to get rid of the extra directories. And I prefer the first option above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contrary to what @MaximilianMairinger wrote, `export * as myNamespace from "./module"` actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your apis in (preferably) two files `/readable.ts` & `/writeable.ts` and rexport them in an `/apiEntry.ts` file under the namespace you want.

```
import * as _writable from "./writeable"
import * as _readable from "./readable"


export const writeable = _writable
export const readable = _readable
```

Yes this looks a bit dirty, to redeclare your modules as constants, but the syntax `export * as namespace from "./module"` does not work. Anyway I believe minifier like terser can mangle this.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-goodall-82i74?file=/src/consumer.ts)

Comment: Thanks! I have tested it and it works great for classes and functions. For types and interfaces however it does not work.

Comment: @Coen Use `export type nameOfType = _nameOfType`

Comment: I don't know how. I'm already doing that in the module, and I cannot do that outside the module because then will conflict with the interfaces/types of the other module/group